# Replace column values in dataframe if they are found in a vector

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm new to R and have been struggling to find the correct syntax to replace values in a column of a dataframe if they appear in a vector, specifically using vectorised operations. For example, if we had the following dataframe (and importing dplyr)

```
library(dplyr)

x = data.frame("grades" = c("A2", "E", "C1", "C2", "Z", "A3", "D", "A2", "F", "B"))
```

what I wanted to do was change *some* of the grades that have no numeric value at the end ("E", "F", "B", elements 2, 9 and 10 respectively), but not others ("Z", element 5), with the same character that they currently have but with a "2" at the end (i.e "E2", "F2", "B2"). That is, after modification, the output vector is expected to be

```
x = data.frame("grades" = c("A2", "E2", "C1", "C2", "Z", "A3", "D2", "A2", "F2", "B2"))
```

I tried specifying a vector of grades to search for and a corresponding vector of grades to change to then using an ifelse

```
y_1 = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F")
y_2 = paste0(y_1, "2")

x = x %>% dplyr::mutate(grades = ifelse(grades %in% y_1, y_2, grades))
```

but didn't get the correct output

```
> x$grades                  
 [1] "A2" "B2" "C1" "C2" "B2" "A3" "A2" "A2" "C2" "D2"
```

In hindsight, it is clear that it shouldn't work as well as I never specified which grade in y_2 should update the grade in y_1. I also tried case_when() and replace() but they both threw an error.

So I was wondering if anyone could explain how to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would use `paste0(grades, "2")` instead of using `y_2`

Try

```
x %>% dplyr::mutate(grades = ifelse(grades %in% y_1, paste0(grades, "2"), grades))
```

will return

```
   grades
1      A2
2      E2
3      C1
4      C2
5       Z
6      A3
7      D2
8      A2
9      F2
10     B2
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively without the vector we can try the below code in `base r`

```r
x$grades <- ifelse(!grepl('\\d$|Z',x$grades),paste0(x$grades,'2'),x$grades)
```

```r
 [1] "A2" "E2" "C1" "C2" "Z"  "A3" "D2" "A2" "F2" "B2"
```